# Getting Exception while getting data from 2 db tables with TABLE_PER_CLASS Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to get data from 2 db table which have same columns in both tables

For that am trying following but getting Exception as

```
- (conn:106433) Table 'r_db.TableBase' doesn't exist
    01:42:54,706 ERROR TableBaseEAO:67 - ::::::::EXCEPTION    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

I am not using any column called clazz_

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class TableBase {

        @Id
        @Column(name="NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="PHONE")
        private String phoneNumber;


        public String getPhoneNumber() {
                return phoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(String phone) {
                this.phoneNumber = phone;
        }
}
```

My entity class for table1

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_1")
public class Table1 extends TableBase {}
```

Entity class for table 2

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_2")
public class Table2 extends TableBase {}
```

following code is to get data in to the list from my 2 db tables

```
public ArrayList<TableBase> getUsers(){
    AppEntityManager appEntMgr = AppEntityManager.getAppEntityManager();
    appEntMgr.startTransaction();
    return (ArrayList<TableBase>) appEntMgr.createQuery("select e from TableBase e")
                .setFirstResult(0)
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Do you have the table `r_db.TableBase` ? What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK i have TableBase table and my hibernate version 3